# Extract values based on pattern out of a line/list

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have list extracted from a json output as below.

```
"Rel_70" "Rel_71" "Dev_795" "Dev_796" "Dev_797" "Devtest_10" "Devtest_12"
```

Out of this, I want to extract values with Dev_* i.e I am interested to extract all values "Dev_795" "Dev_796" "Dev_797" .

Comment: The original JSON document that the values in the question are extracted from would be good to see. It would be _easier_ to work with that than with a line of text with no structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include all "Dev_[digits]" entries:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "} /Dev_[0-9]+/ {print}' inputfile
```

Or, if you wanted specifically only to include those "Dev" entries:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "} /Dev_(795|796|797)/ {print}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tr ' ' '\n' < jsonfile | grep '"Dev_'

perl -lne 'print for /"Dev_\d+"/g' jsonfile

while read -ra A; do for a in "${A[@]}"; do case $a in '"Dev_'* ) echo "$a" ;; esac; done; done < jsonfile
```

Comment: Can you put at least some prose around these answers so that the technically less competent have at least some chance of understanding what is going on here?

Answer (score -1):

```
awk 'ORS=" "{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /Dev_/){print $i}}}' filename
```

output

```
"Dev_795" "Dev_796" "Dev_797"
```